# python, как разбить строку и ввести в массив?

Tags: python, динамические-массивы

Описание:
есть вывод переменной print (var)

```
 cn=testuser45,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test, dc=rdi
 cn=testuser76,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test, dc=rdi
 ................................................
 cn=testuser736,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test, dc=rdi
```

как его ввести в массив вида :

```
massive = [['cn=testuser45', 'ou=Personal', 'o=lab1', 'dc=test', 'dc=rdi'],['cn=testuser45', 'ou=Personal', 'o=lab1', 'dc=test', 'dc=rdi'],.....['cn=testuser736', 'ou=Personal', 'o=lab1', 'dc=test', 'dc=rdi']]
```

Comment: укажите в вопросе как вы получили переменную `var` и какого она типа - это может сильно упростить ответ

Comment: Возможно я неовсем верно задал вопрос, изначально это был массив вида  m1=['cn=testuser45,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test,dc=rdi', 'cn=testuser45,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test,dc=rdi',.....'cn=testuser736,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test,dc=rdi'], потом я его вывел в переменную var (for var in m1: print var), в надежде привести в массив нужного мне вида

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [318]: m1
Out[318]:
['cn=testuser45,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test,dc=rdi',
 'cn=testuser45,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test,dc=rdi',
 'cn=testuser736,ou=Personal,o=lab1,dc=test,dc=rdi']

In [319]: res = [x.split(',') for x in m1]

In [320]: res
Out[320]:
[['cn=testuser45', 'ou=Personal', 'o=lab1', 'dc=test', 'dc=rdi'],
 ['cn=testuser45', 'ou=Personal', 'o=lab1', 'dc=test', 'dc=rdi'],
 ['cn=testuser736', 'ou=Personal', 'o=lab1', 'dc=test', 'dc=rdi']]
```